# Database design user tables split or single

Tags: sql, database-design

I just wanted to see what others think about this subject. I've got a project with a rather large number of unique information on each user. Now, given that there are no redundancies and that there are a large number of users - would splitting up the data into smaller tables make it faster?

I did try a test with 1000 queries where one had 87 columns and another where only login information was stored separately. In the one I got 1372ms, the other 879ms; seems to be faster at a glance, but likely someone has more experience than me and can give their point of view on this?

Comment: Could you please insert some capital letters and full stops here and there? Preferably to convert your block of words into sentences.

Comment: You have split the table vertically (by columns), not horizontally (by users), correct? Please provide more details about your measurement - preferably the exact DDL and DML SQL that you used.

Comment: Ok mysql inodb 240000 entries 87 unique columns of data. Indexed by username and 5 foreing keys

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo although I agree, given your 26k reputation, you could have improved the question yourself by editing. To Netcfmx: please watch your language! If you expect other people to invest time in helping you with your problem, we may at least expect that you invest **some** time to formulate a good, *readable* question!

Answer (score 6):

In your test, if you are querying from the large and small table using "SELECT *", to return all the columns, then yes, of course the larger table is going to take longer since it has to return more data.  However, in a production app, the queries in your application should be targeted, returning only the columns that you need.

If each table has the same indexing and data that is being filtered on, and each returns the same selected columns, the result set should likely return in roughly same time.  However, I should add that time can be very misleading when considering performance testing.  There are many factors with a database server that change continuously, and have nothing to do with the queries you are running, but absolutely can impact their run time. Instead of time as a measurement, try looking at the logical reads.

As for your design question, either way will technically work.  However, you may want to consider how often particular data needs to be accessed in order to help out the rest of your development team.  If you have 20% of the columns that are queried 80% of the time, you may want to consider having those in their own table.  This should help avoid significant time being spent by new developers to your team from having to sift through numerous columns of generally unimportant data just to identify what they want to query.

Additionally, from a physical design standpoint, you could place the 20% table that requires frequent access on higher performing disk drives and the 80% data on lower performing disk drives if cost is an issue.

Comment: Nice, well-written answer with good pointers for the OP :)

Comment: Very nice! Thank you.